# Angular date picker hide show with button click

Tags: angular

I have 3 text boxes and a button. on button click, I want to show date picker and on select of date, I want to populate the date, month and year in those 3 text boxes.

I tried using the library "ng2-datepicker".

```
<ng-datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" [options]="options" [isOpened]="isOpened" [position] = "position"></ng-datepicker>

<button (click)="isOpened = !isOpened">select</button>
```

Here "isOpened" property controls the show hide of date picker and visible as a single textbox. I am not able to perform the show hide also. But passing true or false directly works

Also, I am not finding a proper solution to achieve this with 3 text boxes. Please provide if you found some useful links on click of a button

Note: I don't want to use Jquery controls

Comment: Hi, you can simply use primeng to achieve your goal. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ngx-bootstrap`? It's quite verbose and works well for me. 
If you still want to use ng2-datepicker in your solution - maybe setup a Stackblitz replicate your problem so we can try to solve it.